# Mirrored Object Clipping Through Original Object

Tags: modeling

I am designing a tank model and the mirrored object on the left is clipping through the original object on the right, both sides are supposed to be symmetrical but clearly that's not the case, how would I fix this?

I have provided the Blend File in a Dropbox File:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8tsmf58dx10u8ms/tank1.blend?dl=0

[image]

Here is a picture of the object with the mirror modifier turned off

[image]

Comment: Hello, why don't you delete the left part of the object? Mirror modifier is precisely supposed to mirror a part on the other side of the chosen axis. Also enable the Clipping option of the Mirror so that the vertices stick to the axis

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't have the clipping option enabled on the modifier. Go to the modifier menu and click it and that should fix things.